# Sorting a data file and how to approach it

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I need a little guidance in how to sort a specific file in python and how to approach it in the fastest way possible because of the amount of data I have.

So the data file has thousands of molecules inside the file and each molecule has atom numbers that need to be sorted.

```
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
```

The beginning of the numbers that need to be sorted start off with that specific string

Example of data that needs to be sorted

```
 76 N       -1.8470    -2.5910     1.7540 N.am  1 TRP1  -0.3940 BACKBONE
 47 O       -2.4960    -2.0500     2.8860 O.3   1 TRP1  -0.4360 BACKBONE
 50 O       -0.0550    -2.9590     3.0930 O.2   1 TRP1  -0.5700 BACKBONE
```

The atom number in front in this case would be 76 needs to be sorted into

```
47
50
76
```

The line atom numbers end with

```
@<TRIPOS>BOND
```

I feel like it would be simpler in recognizing the data start line then bubble sorting and then recognizing the end line if possible.
So I have been looking into sort methods like merge sort or quick sort which would be a lot better approach and how to begin? Roughly there are 300000 lines to process so the most efficient method is key here